# FIFO Mechanism in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

Is there an Easy way to implement FIFO in RichTextBox control?

Actually i have a testing tool that produce more than 1000 lines within a minute that is why i want to limit the total number lines and when a new line adds in the control the Last line should be removed.

Comment: Knowing when to start deleting lines is the problem.  Using Lines.Count is too expensive.  But it becomes easy if you can guarantee that only a single line gets added.  We need simplifications like that to give you a good answer, document them in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Today I came across [**Infinite-Scroll design pattern**](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/). I think it might help.

**OLD ANSWER:**

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();

int max = 2;

int n = 0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lines.Insert(0,n.ToString());

    richTextBox1.Text = string.Join("\n", lines.Take(max).ToArray<string>());

    n++;
}
```

This is very simple FIFO. Also in `List<string> l` you will have log at all the times :)

Comment: :( This is not that simple there are many formating scenarios i have to make them on each entry and it will be performance factor please consider the max value = 10,000

Comment: it slows down the processing as there are number of threads writing logs and you know UI object can only be accessed from UI Thread :(

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question but do you read all of the 1000 messages in a minute?
Is there a way (or already is) to log only messages from a 'level'.
quote from java:

> ```
> * SEVERE (highest value)
> * WARNING
> * INFO
> * CONFIG
> * FINE
> * FINER
> * FINEST (lowest value)
> ```

For example:
normally you would have: message 1(debug) and message 2(SEVERE )
Prefix each line according to their level:

- 1:message 1
- 7:message 2

Now you can modify your testing tool to log only a certain level. 7 logs all, 1 logs only 1 etc.
Result is less unnecessary logging and readable output (for example 2 messages should arise right after each other, but because of threading there are 20 messages between in the logging...)